# To configure MySQL Enterprise Workbench for Incremental Backup with Online Backup option

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, backup

Could not acquire management access for administration
RuntimeError:Could not initialize WMI interface: Workbench.wmiOpenSession():Could not connect to target machine.

When i am trying to configure MySQL Enterprise Workbench for incremental backup with (online backup) option then i am getting the above error.

I am able to take full backup from MySQL Enterprise Workbench tool. I am accessing MySQL Database through remotely. what i shall do in this scenario. In my Network Environment there is SSH tunnel as well as firewall.

Any one suggest to me.
[image]

Comment: Struggling with the same issue here...